# Python cannot import, unknown location

Tags: python, function, module, pycharm

I've three file in pycharm project like,

```
project
├── main.py 
├── parser.py
└── test.py
```

Both parser.py and test.py have the same code.

```
def test():
    print('test')
```

But I can only execute main.py with below and it outputs `test`

```
from test import test

test()
```

While when I execute main.py with below,

```
from parser import test

test()
```

it output's

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "C:/Users/lf/Desktop/jye_parser/main.py", line 1, in <module>
>     from parser import test
> ImportError: cannot import name 'test' from 'parser' (unknown location)
>
> Process finished with exit code 1
> ```

Here is the project architecture. I can use `Ctrl` + `Left Click` to jump to the `test` function in main.py in both case.

[image]

Comment: Is it because your project name is named `parser` too?

Comment: @ycx actually my project name is `jye_parser`.

Comment: @ycx I added the project architecture.

Comment: It seems to me like you're either missing an `__init__.py` for it to look into in your `jye_parser` or when you are running your script, your script is not looking in the correct working directory for the `parser`. You should try printing `import os; os.getcwd()` to check

Comment: @ycx `print(os.getcwd())` outputs `C:\Users\lf\Desktop\jye_parser`

Comment: how about using a different `def test` name? Try `def test1`. It could be that your current run has already previously loaded the `test` function and somehow this is affecting it

Comment: Could you first just `import parser` and then show the result of `parser.__file__`?

Comment: AFAIR `parser` is on some platforms a special builtin that has precedence.

Comment: @Sraw `import parser
print(parser.__file__)` output `AttributeError: module 'parser' has no attribute '__file__'`

Comment: @ycx same error with `test1`

Comment: @KlausD. Thank you. You're right. Can you make it an answer.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It's because parser is a library in python. Use another name for parser file.

Comment: This worked for me, which is odd, because I created it on one machine and it ran fine locally, but when I imported the update from my git repo and tried to run it on another device it suddenly got the error.

Comment: I think the problem is that your first machine doesn't have the parser package but the second one has it.